# How do make a progress bar with TraitsUI and Qt5?

Tags: qt5, traits, enthought, traitsui

In the past, I used the `traitsui.wx.themed_slider_editor.ThemedSliderEditor` to build a progress bar with a TraitsUI application with wx backend,

```
Item("model.progress",
      label="Progress",
      show_label=False,
      style='readonly',
      editor=ThemedSliderEditor(low=0.0,
                                high=1.0,
                                increment=0.05,
                                show_value=False))
```

What are the options for a **progress bar** with a QT5 backend? I see there is this https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/traitsui/qt4/progress_editor.py but it seems to be for Qt4. So I'm not too sure how to continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt5 should be supported. See https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/CHANGES.txt. If you encounter problems with this, please open an issue on GH.

---

Update:

Try something like this (partial, not tested):

```
from traitsui.editors import ProgressEditor
(other imports etc)...

class ProgressDialog(HasTraits):
    progress = Int
    view = View(Item('progress', show_label=False,
                     editor=ProgressEditor(min=0, max=100)),
                title='Progress'
                )
```

Comment: OK, so just use `traitsui.qt4.progress_editor`? Do you have an example on using this editor?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but just updated response with a suggested approach.

Comment: This is currently broken with QT https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/issues/487